# Do all metals expand on heating?

Tags: metal, solid-state-chemistry

This question came up when I was reading about substances with negative thermal expansion. The article by Takenaka [[1](https://doi.org/10.1088/1468-6996/13/1/013001)] gives a good list of materials displaying negative thermal expansion. I noticed that almost all the substances mentioned are alloys or crystals, with not a single pure metal included.

This raised the question: **Do all metals expand on heating?** If so, why? If not, give an example of a metal that contracts on heating.

#### References

1. Takenaka, K. Negative Thermal Expansion Materials: Technological Key for Control of Thermal Expansion. *Sci. Technol. Adv. Mater.* **2012**, 13 (1), 013001. DOI: [10.1088/1468-6996/13/1/013001](https://doi.org/10.1088/1468-6996/13/1/013001).

Comment: @andselisk how do you get that "reference" text? Do you copy it from somewhere or do you type it out manually?

Comment: There sure are also pure metals like that, as mentioned in earlier answer.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) and [ACS style file](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/american-chemical-society.csl). There is also a simplified online version, [ZoteroBib](https://zbib.org/), if you don't feel like installing and configuring stuff.

Comment: Depends on the temperature range. Many pure metals do some odd things at low temperature.

Comment: @Mithoron no. My question specifically targets _metals_ and not _materials_. Please suggest an edit if that is not clear in the question.

Comment: From andselisk's answer^ "(...) certain liquid-solid phase transitions are accompanied by negative thermal expansion (NTE). This also includes **elements (Si,Ga,Ge,Sb,Bi,Pu)** - your question is subset to earlier one and metals are also "materials".